# Can I check variables in a constructor body that were set in the initialization list?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization-list

I have doubts on how the constructor's body works in case of initialization lists. If the value passed by the constructor are not admitted value and an exception needs to be thrown, is it correct to do something like this?

```
Foo(int a_) : a(a_) {
  if (a>0)
    throw std::invalid_argument("positive value!");
};
```

I am having doubt on how this is evaluated, in case of more complex situations.

Comment: What is an "admitted value"? It's an `int`; it can assume any value.

Comment: Yes sure but let's say that the Foo class can't accept positive int, would it be ok to throw an exception that way? In what order gets the body / the assignment executed? From my compiler, the body gets executed after the assignment to the variables; is this undefined or defined behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), it is absolutely safe to assume the initializer list will be completed before the 'body' of the constructor is executed (bolding of item 4 is mine):

> The order of member initializers in the list is irrelevant: the actual
>   order of initialization is as follows
>
> - 1 If the constructor is for the most-derived class, virtual base classes are initialized in the order in which they appear in
>     depth-first left-to-right traversal of the base class declarations
>     (left-to-right refers to the appearance in base-specifier lists)
> - 2 Then, direct base classes are initialized in left-to-right order as they appear in this class's base-specifier list
> - 3 Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.
> - 4 **Finally, the body of the constructor is executed**

Now, although **cppreference** isn't the actual standard, it's normally accurate on such matters.

EDIT: The [draft C++14 (§ 12.6.2) standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (pp. 283-284 of that PDF) confirms what **cppreference** states. *(Yes, I know the OP specified `C++11` - but I couldn't get a link to that standard online, and I very much doubt that the standard in that matter has changed between 11, 14 and 17!)*